# Trying to send checkbox value(s) from form to email in PHP

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

It has been years since I was in web development but have dabbled in PHP in the past, so I guess you could say I am a newbie at PHP. I am trying to build a simple form for a job application using PHP I want the form to be filled out and then emailed upon submit.

I have researched this site as well as others and am unable to get this to work. I cannot get the job value to show up in email:

Here is my HTML code:

```
            <label>Position: check all you are interested in </label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="job[]" value="General Pickle Production">General Pickle Production
            <input type="checkbox" name="job[]" value="Fryer">Fryer
            <input type="checkbox" name="job[]" value="Sales">Sales
            <input type="checkbox" name="job[]" value="Manager">Manager
            <input type="checkbox" name="job[]" value="Overnights">Overnights<br>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
    $aJob = $_POST['job'];
     if(empty($aJob)) 
   {
     echo("You didn't select any job position.");
   } 
   else 
   {
     $N = count($aJob);

     echo("You selected $N job(s): ");
     for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
     {
       echo($aJob[$i] . " ");
     }
   }
```

When I hit submit on the form the above will show each job selected on the form page but I guess I am not sure how to send this to my email upon the submit. Below is the code I have sending the variables to my email:

```
    $content = $_POST['name'] . " " . $_POST['lastname'] . " \n";
    $content .= $_POST['address'] . " \n";
    $content .= "Position(s) applied for: " . $_POST['aJob'] . " \n";
```

Do I need to put my for loop in $content section somewhere to display the jobs? I guess I am not sure what that format would look like here?

I appreciate any help you could offer. 
Thank you. J

Comment: @Thefourthbird your args are backwards for implode

Answer (score 0):

```
$content .= "Position(s) applied for: ";
$content .= implode(',' $_POST['aJob']);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you use `name="job[]"` for the input elements. To get the values from the `$_POST` array, I think you should use `$_POST['job']` instead of `$_POST['aJob']`.

If you want to separate them by comma, you could for example do it like this using [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
if (isset($_POST['job'])) {
    $content .= "Position(s) applied for: " . implode(",", $_POST['job']) . " \n";
}
```

Comment: `implode($glue, $pieces)`